# How to center a UIView using storyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a view inside another view which I create using storyboard, now I want to position my inner view center vertically. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First select the View and place in center of the nib,Then Tick the Horizontal Center in Container and Vertical Center in Container**

[image]

**Then Give Height and Width to the View,Your View is now centered.**

[image]

Comment: I honestly don't see the images you attached but I get what you're saying. Thanks, it worked now.

Comment: Dear @Mukesh, can we add a view by percentage? I mean add a View inside SafeAreaView and add its width by percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSLayoutConstraint (Center Horizontally, Center Vertically) with parent view. And you need set constraint (width, height) for this view. 
[image]